# broader meaning of twin prime constant?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-gaps, twin-primes

It appears that the twin prime constant has meaning outside of the strict twin prime constant. I attempted to keep this post as short as possible.

Definitions:

1. Let $p,q$ represent primes and let $n$ be a positive integer.
2. $\pi(n)$ has its usual meaning.
3. Let $p_k$ be the $k^{th}$ prime. ($p_1 = 2$).

From the first $n$ positive integers,  consider integers that are $\not\equiv a_1 \bmod p$ for all $p_1 \leq p \leq \sqrt{n}$.  Let us call these integers {$a_1$}-primes and let $\pi^{\text{\{$a_1$\}}}(n)$ represent their count.  So we remove integers in residue classes $a_1 \bmod p$ where $p_1 \leq p \leq \sqrt{n}$. Slight deviation from definition but we will assume {$0$}-primes as the usual primes.

Let {$a_1,a_2$}-primes represent {$a_1$}-primes that are $\not\equiv a_2 \bmod p$ (for all $p_2 \leq p \leq \sqrt{n}$) and let $\pi^{\text{\{$a_1, a_2$\}}}(n)$ represent their count.  So we remove integers in residue classes $a_1 \bmod p$ (for all $p_1 \leq p \leq \sqrt{n}$) and $a_2 \bmod p$ (for all $p_2 \leq p \leq \sqrt{n}$).

and so on.

We can state the most generic claim for removing integers from two residue classes.

\begin{align}
\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{\left(\frac{\pi^{\text{\{$a_1,a_2$\}}}(n)}{\pi^{\text{\{$a_1$\}}}(n)}\right)}{\left(\frac{\pi^{\text{\{$a_1$\}}}(n)}{n}\right)}= 2C_2 \tag{1}
\end{align}

We can read the above as saying that the proportion of count of {$a_1,a_2$}-primes to  {$a_1$}-primes is $2C_2$ times the proportion of count of {$a_1$}-primes to $n$.

We have to be sure that we are observing the definition of {$a_1, a_2$}-primes. Equation (1) is true for {$a_1,a_2$} = {$0,1$} or {$0,2$} or {$1,2$} or {$0,-2$} or {$0,-4$} but not {$0,-6$} as the last one doesn't strictly follow the {$a_1,a_2$}-primes definition.

I find this result fascinating assuming it is true. I don't know if I have a proof but I do have an argument.

Let $\alpha_2$ be an estimate for the proportion of count of {$a_1,a_2$}-primes to  {$a_1$}-primes and let $\alpha_1$ be an estimate for the proportion of count of {$a_1$}-primes to $n$. We can represent $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ by:
\begin{align}
\alpha_1 &= \prod\limits_{\substack{p \text{ $prime$ } \\ 2 \leq p \leq \sqrt{n}}} \frac{p-1}{p} \\\\
\alpha_2 &= \prod\limits_{\substack{p \text{ $prime$ } \\ 3 \leq p \leq \sqrt{n}}} \frac{p-2}{p-1} \\\\
\end{align}

as $\frac{p-1}{p}$ represents the number of residue classes of interest to the total and similarly $\frac{p-2}{p-1}$ represents the number of residue classes of interest to the total.(there is implicit use of Dirichlet's theorem for primes in AP and Chebotarev's density theorem).  Although $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ are not perfect estimators (Mertens' theorems), it is easy to see that as $n\to\infty$, their ratio $\frac{\alpha_2}{\alpha_1}$ tends to $2C_2$. In other words, the error in the estimators  $\alpha_2$ and $\alpha_1$ cancels out when we take their ratio.

Question: Does any of this make sense? Is it correct?

Comment: Does “for $p_1 \leq p \leq \sqrt{n}$” mean “for *all* primes $p$ such that…”? If so please add “all” for clarity. Look up the heuristic probabilistic reasoning behind the Bateman-Horn conjecture. It easily leads to such constants as $2C_2$, but it is pretty hopeless to expect to get actual proofs about (real) prime counts in this way.

Comment: Instead of saying you “drop integers in residue classes…”, I suggest saying “remove integers in residue classes…” because to drop something in something could be misread as dropping *into* (i.e., putting  into) that something, which is the exact opposite of what you want!

Comment: made the edits. Thank you @KCd.