# question on estimator for $\frac{\pi(n)}{n}$ and $\frac{\pi_2(n)}{\pi(n)}$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-gaps, twin-primes, goldbachs-conjecture

$\pi(n)$ and $\pi_2(n)$ represent the count of primes and count of twin primes $\leq n$ respectively.

Suppose we want to estimate $\frac{\pi(n)}{n}$. One way which obviously is not error-free is to note that we are essentially taking the fraction $\frac{p-1}{p}$ for every prime $p$ in $2 \leq p \leq \sqrt{n}$. Let us call this estimate $\alpha_1$ and the accuracy of this estimate as $acc_1$.

\begin{align}
\alpha_1 &= \prod\limits_{\substack{p \text{ $\text{prime}$ } \\ 2 \leq p \leq \sqrt{n}}} \frac{p-1}{p} \\\\
acc_1 &= \frac{\alpha_1}{\left(\frac{\pi(n)}{n}\right)}
\end{align}

In a similar fashion, suppose we want to estimate $\frac{\pi_2(n)}{\pi(n)}$. One way which obviously is not error-free is to note that we are essentially taking the fraction $\frac{p-2}{p-1}$ for every prime $p$ in $3 \leq p \leq \sqrt{n}$. Let us call this estimate $\alpha_2$ and the accuracy of this estimate as $acc_2$.

\begin{align}
\alpha_2 &= \prod\limits_{\substack{p \text{ prime } \\ 3 \leq p \leq \sqrt{n}}} \frac{p-2}{p-1} \\\\
acc_2 &= \frac{\alpha_2}{\left(\frac{\pi_2(n)}{\pi(n)}\right)}
\end{align}

**Claim**

I claim that the ratio of the accuracies $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{acc_1}{acc_2} = 1$ since although the estimators $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ are not error-free, and since $\alpha_2 = 2C_2\alpha_1$ in the limit, the errors in $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ get cancelled when we take the ratio $\frac{\alpha_1}{\alpha_2}$. This leads us to the following conclusion:

\begin{align}
\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \pi_2(n) = 2C_2 \frac{\pi^2(n)}{n}
\end{align}
where $C_2$ is the twin prime constant.

I am struggling to understand what is wrong with my claim. Appreciate any guidance.

EDIT: I want to clarify what has $\alpha_2$ got to do with $\pi_2(n)$?

Consider primes $\leq n$. Of these primes, we want to find primes that are not congruent to $k \bmod p$ (for non-zero $k$) and for $p$ in $3 \leq p \leq \sqrt{n}$. We know the primes (possibly excluding one prime) get equally distributed (becomes more equal for large $n$) among the $p-1$ residue classes (for prime $3$). Of these $p-1$ residue classes, we choose $p-2$ of them. So we take a proportion $\frac{p-2}{p-1}$. We then distribute these primes among the $p-1$ residue classes for prime $5$ and so on for each primes $\leq \sqrt{n}$. And so we get an estimate for the proportion of primes that are $\not\equiv k \bmod p$ is $\alpha_2$. (This estimate is not error-free). For $k = -2$, we get the count of twin primes or $\pi_2(n)$. For $k = -4$, we get the count of cousin primes or $\pi_4(n)$. For $k = n$, (for even $n$), we get the count of Goldbach primes.

Comment: The assumption that the errors will cancel is likely the source of some of the most significant of the problems with the claim.  Have you gotten any data to verify your claim?

Comment: If $\alpha_1$ was a perfect estimator, then $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \alpha_1 = \frac{1}{\log n}$. But this is not true. Based on Mertens' we get $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \alpha_1 = \frac{2e^{-\gamma}}{\log n}$ where $\gamma$ is Euler constant. And the entire error in $\alpha_2$ is coming from $\alpha_1$ as former is a multiple of the latter in the limit.

Comment: How do you know that $\alpha_2$ has anything to do with $\pi_2(n)$; for $\alpha_1$ one has the prime number theorem etc, but for $\alpha_2$ we do not know anything beyond conjectures; while unlikely it is definitely possible that $\pi_2(n)$ is bounded for example or it may not be $C_2n/log^2 n$ but $C_2n/log^{100}n$ for what we know

Comment: Good question. In general $\alpha_2$ gives us the proportion of primes that are also not congruent to some (non zero)$k \bmod p$ for all $p$ in $3 \leq p \leq \sqrt{n}$. In this case $k =-2$. See also this post. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4832282/broader-meaning-of-twin-prime-constant

Comment: Which is why $\pi_4(n)$ also will have the same asymptotic behavior.

Comment: Also, we can apply this to Goldbach Conjecture as well where we look for primes $q$ that are not congruent to $2n\bmod p$ for all $p$ in $3 \leq p \leq \sqrt{2n}$.  The count of Goldbach primes for even integer $2n$ will be asymptotically $\geq 2C_2 \frac{\pi^2(2n)}{2n}$, where the equality holds for $2n = 2^k$ or $2n=2r$ for $r$ prime, and the inequality for all other $2n$. Looking forward to your comments. Thank you

Comment: Dear @Conrad does all of this make sense now? If not please do ask questions so I can help clarify. Thank you very much!

Comment: Again there is no proof just heuristics based off hand waving - I would suggest to read some sieve theory where this type of reasoning is made rigorous; to convince yourself try and write a rigorous proof using estimates for your "get equally distributed" or for "we distribute" etc;

Comment: In other words one still doesn't know if there is any relation between $\pi_2$ and $\alpha_2$ - Brun showed that $\pi_2(x) << \frac {x(\log \log x)^2)}{\log^2 x}$ which I do not think has been improved much if at all; Nathanson book on Additive NT volume 1 Classical Bases has a very gentle introduction to these topics

Comment: Thank you so much. I really appreciate it. As a final thought, I was under the impression that Dirichlet's theorem on primes in AP along with Chebotarev density theorem imply that primes are asymptotically uniformly distributed among the residue classes. I could be interpreting this wrong... I understood this as primes that are $1, 2 \bmod 3$ get asymptotically uniformly distributed among the $4$ residue classes $\bmod 5$ and primes that are $1,2,3,4 \bmod 5$ get asymptotically uniformly distributed among the $6$ residue classes $\bmod 7$ and so on.